# Como manter a barra de rolagem do navegador no topo ao carregar uma nova página com angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Estou utilizando módulos criados com node e Angular, por especificação do projeto tivemos que tirar a # da navegação. Porem, quando clico em um link que está no footer e carrega outra página a barra de rolagem do navegador continua no footer e não vai para o topo como uma navegação tradicional. Alguém sabe me falar se existe alguma configuração que resolva este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Com o ngRouter ou uiRouter, você pode monitorar as mudanças de rotas. E a cada mudança ou em determinadas mudanças, aplicar o scroll para a posição 0.

Exemplo: (para uiRouter)

```
angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope)]{
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
        window.scrollTop(0,0);
    })
});
```

Se estiver usando o ngRouter altere o `$stateChangeStart`por `$routeChangeStart`